# How to get name of a required page in CherryPy?

Tags: python, web, cherrypy

I know that in CherryPy requested pages are bound to the functions with the same names. For example

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    def hello(self):
        return "Hello Hello2!"
    index.exposed = True
    hello.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

if we go to `127.0.0.1:8080/hello` we get `Hello Hello2!`.

However, I need a more flexible behavior. I do not know in advance what URL will be requested, I just want to be able to determine with CherryPy the requested URL. For example if `127.0.0.1:8080/goodbye` is requested, I want to know that some variable is equal to `goodbye` and than based on the found value, I start a certain functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 For @Burhan's answer. However for a simple working example you'll only need something like this:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def default(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return "Hello world!" + cherrypy.url()

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

Comment: Although the mappings example is more flexible and explicit, your answer might actually be all the OP is actually looking for, +1.

Answer (score 1):

CherryPy supports many kinds of route mapping (called dispatching). From the [dispatch documentation](http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/dispatching.html?highlight=routesdispatcher#other-dispatchers):

```
def root_index(name):
    return "Hello, %s!" % name

def branch_leaf(size):
    return str(int(size) + 3)

mappings = [
    (r'^/([^/]+)$', root_index),
    (r'^/branch/leaf/(\d+)$', branch_leaf),
    ]
```

You can see the `root_index` method is taking any arbitrary URL; and passing the url as the first argument (in this case *`name`*) to the method.

You can modify the regular expression to be more inclusive - the expression in the documentation skips `/`, so `/hello/world/` will not be captured.